# Android SDK doesn`t create folders after installing, and doesn`t accept existant

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk

After installing Android Studio it doesn't downloaded any SDK or have any created folders but keeps arguing with me when I try to create any by myself. I've installed JDK, there's no problems, but SDK doesn't come over.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried different options from Stack Overflow as "Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later" topic, "Android Studio SDK location", "
"Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error - ", "No Android SDK found - Android Studio"
"Android-studio Selected directory is not valid home for Android SDK - Stack Overflow", "Error "Dependent package with key emulator not found" while updating Android SDK and tools", "android - This download could not be finalized from the interim state", "
Android Studio 3.0.1 Error: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly"

Comment: It should install an SDK as part of the setup wizard when you first install it - if that didn't happen, you should be able to just install one by checking its box in the SDK Platforms window below your first screenshot, then hit apply. You'll need to put a path in that location box though, to say where SDKs should be stored on your computer - the path in your second screenshot is the default for Windows. (You also don't need to install the JDK, the IDE has OpenJDK built in and it uses that by default)

Comment: i`ve tried to install SDK, but untill it doesn`t have a location, it doesnt allow me to add any tools.

Comment: Honestly if you only just installed it, it's probably easier to uninstall and install it again, and make sure you use the default options. That should automatically set up the SDK for you. If you want to try and fix this installation, you could try setting up the SDK yourself with this: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager . I don't have any experience with it though, sorry! It *might* work in Android Studio when you unzip the stuff like it tells you to (it might recognise that directory as "an existing SDK installation") but I don't know